# create web service from wsdl java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I need to do web service created from wsdl. WSDL divided into 2 wsdl file.

1st one is named Iblabla.wsdl (for example) and looks like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="Iblabla" targetNamespace="http://vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Interfaces" xmlns:tns="http://vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Types" xmlns:tns0="http://vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Interfaces" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Interfaces">
        <xsd:import namespace="vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Types" schemaLocation="../Types/Iblabla.xsd"/>            
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="SendMessageRequestMsg">
<wsdl:part element="tns:SendMessage" name="SendMessageParameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SendMessageResponseMsg">
<wsdl:part element="tns:SendMessageResponse" name="SendMessageResult"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SendMessage_sendMessageFaultMsg">
<wsdl:part element="tns:SendMessageFault1_SendMessageFault" name="sendMessageFault"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="Iblabla">
<wsdl:operation name="SendMessage">
  <wsdl:input message="tns0:SendMessageRequestMsg" name="SendMessageRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns0:SendMessageResponseMsg" name="SendMessageResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="tns0:SendMessage_sendMessageFaultMsg" name="sendMessageFault"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

2nd one is named IblablaHttp_Service.wsdl (for example) and looks like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="IblablaHttp_Service" targetNamespace="http://vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Interfaces/Binding2" xmlns:Port_0="http://vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Interfaces" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:this="http://vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Interfaces/Binding2" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:import location="Iblabla.wsdl" namespace="http://vlavlavla/blabla/v10/Interfaces"/>
<wsdl:binding name="blablaHttpBinding" type="Port_0:Iblabla">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="SendMessage">
  <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
  <wsdl:input name="SendMessageRequest">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="SendMessageResponse">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
  <wsdl:fault name="sendMessageFault">
    <soap:fault name="sendMessageFault" use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="IblablaHttpService">
<wsdl:port binding="this:blablaHttpBinding" name="blablaHttpPort">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:9080/SerrviceSampleTypesWeb/sca/blablaService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

How to generate and create web-service from this divided 2 wsdl files?

Comment: you can only create a web service client using wsdl or using netbeans you can use this link (http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/5-techniques-create-web-servic)

Comment: @BhargavModi so i cant create web-service, can create only client? And how to create client with 2 divided wsdls?

Comment: well...a WSDL defines a web service.  You could implement the webservice from the WSDL, of course.  However, you might have to alter the URL's....